# pandas fillna with selected multiple columns is slower than its over looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I was taught as we shouldn't use loops in pandas because it is usually slower than pandas operation. However, I experimented as following then the result is what I didn't expect.

#### Create a dataframe with nan values

```
np.random.seed(1)

one = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10000000)
two = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10000000)
three = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10000000)

one.ravel()[np.random.choice(one.size, 100000, replace=False)] = np.nan
two.ravel()[np.random.choice(two.size, 100000, replace=False)] = np.nan
three.ravel()[np.random.choice(three.size, 100000, replace=False)] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': one, 'two': two, 'three': three})
```

#### Replace nan values in selected columns to 0

```
exclusives = {
    'one',
}
columns = [col for col in df.columns if col not in exclusives]

%%time
df[columns] = df[columns].fillna(0)

CPU times: user 224 ms, sys: 178 ms, total: 402 ms
Wall time: 459 ms
```

```
%%time
for column in df.columns:
    if column not in exclusives:
        df[column] = df[column].fillna(0)

CPU times: user 141 ms, sys: 47.5 ms, total: 189 ms
Wall time: 193 ms
```

I think the first one looks cleaner, and I expected the first one is also way faster but the result is the opposite. Does anyone know why it happens and explain the reason why most pands users chose the first one in real life?

Comment: Interesting observation! I cannot explain the performance difference, but there's an obvious difference other than the explicit loops: `df[columns].fillna(0)` uses the `fillna` method of a `DataFrame` while `df[column].fillna(0)` uses the `fillna` method of a `Series`.